# r - How to subset a dataframe based on another dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

I have data `dat` like this:

```
s    A     chan
10   0.1   1
20   0.2   1
30   0.3   1
40   0.5   1
50   0.7   1
60   0.5   1
10   0.1   2
20   0.3   2
30   0.4   2
40   0.5   2
50   0.6   2
60   0.6   2
10   0.2   3
20   0.2   3
30   0.3   3
40   0.4   3
50   0.5   3
40   0.7   3
10   0.2   4
20   0.2   4
30   0.3   4
40   0.3   4
50   0.6   4
60   0.8   4
```

and I want to subset my data frame `dat` based on s (time) for each chan (channel) with a data frame `df` like this

```
s    chan
10    1
20    2
30    3
40    4
```

If I use `dat %>% filter(s %in% df$s)` I get each value for every channel like this:

```
s    A     chan
10   0.1   1
20   0.2   1
30   0.3   1
40   0.5   1
10   0.1   2
20   0.3   2
30   0.4   2
40   0.5   2
10   0.2   3
20   0.2   3
30   0.3   3
40   0.4   3
10   0.2   4
20   0.2   4
30   0.3   4
40   0.3   4
```

but what I actualy want it this:

```
s    A     chan
10   0.1   1
20   0.3   2
30   0.3   3
40   0.3   4
```

How can I achieve this result?

Comment: `dat %>% filter(s == chan)`

Comment: ok, in this case it would acutally work, I should have used differnt numbers for s.

Answer (score 2):

what you are looking for is `semi_join`; it filters rows from left data frame based on the presence or absence of matches in right data frame,

```
semi_join(dat, df, by = c("s", "chan"))
```

Comment: That does the trick with my test data, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do it

```
dat[which(dat[,3]==df[1:4,2] & dat[,1]==df[1:4,1]),]
```

`1:4` being the range of lines in `df`.